# CSS works as localhost but not by server address

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iis

After having a couple issues with CSS, I downloaded the menu code from http://responsivemultimenu.com.

The code works great on my local machine in both IE and FF when calling as LocalHost. When I copied it over to our intranet server (Windows 2003, IIS 6) and call the page by it's server address, the css fails to fully load in IE, but works in firefox. I tried it on a second server (Windows 2008, IIS 7.5) with the same result. To see if it was my browser, I had a couple other people call that page on the server from their computer with the same result.

I have not changed any of the html, css or js code from the download.

It seems like some of the css loads but not all of it. I am completely stumped.

Here is a screen shot of it in FireFox and what it is supposed to look like. 
[image: Here is a screen shot of it in FireFox and what it is supposed to look like]

Here is a screenshot of it in Internet explorer. It's not working. 
[image: Here is a screenshot of it in Internet explorer. It's not working.]

I really need to figure this out of why the css is not loading. What could be blocking it? What do I need to change either in my browser or on my server?

Comment: Hard to tell what’s going on without being able to look at *anything*. But you should know that Internet Explorer is often configured to use a compatibility mode for intranet sites to “increase compatibility” with corporate web applications. You can verify that with the IE developer tools.

Comment: That has got to be one of the dumbest default settings in Internet Explorer. Unchecking "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" fixed it. 
I guess, I am going to have to figure something else out. There is no way I am going to be able to get 2000 people to change that setting. I need to build something that is going to work.

Comment: You can put some meta tag in your HTML to tell IE not to do that. So you do not need to change all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem as yours after doing a research without any help then i tried to access the folder where css files store and figure out that i don't have permission when i changed it, it worked perfectly[image]

Answer (score 2):

try to clear the cache in browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDyoG.png)

At least it is work for me in chrome, I believe there is the same function in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Check on your browser console in the Developer mode, in Chrome you can open it with <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, I don't use Firefox. Once opened, reload the page, and check for any errors while loading your website. Maybe you need to update the route/location of your CSS file within your file, for example, your file is stored in `/home/my_website/style/file.css` and you can access it locally, but maybe when the browser is loading your website, it doesn't find the file/route.

Answer (score 0):

Check your link href via inspecting page, mine was not properly done for localhost.

Answer (score 0):

try with rename your css file and it's link in html page

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35537004)